# Push Notification for Windows 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

What I have in my mind:

1. The app gets a URI.
2. The app sends the URI to my DB.
3. An admin panel where admin sends a message which goes as notification to all the URI present in DB.

I have found this [code](https://phpwindowsphonepush.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#windowsphonepush.php) which can send the notification to the URI in my DB.

However I am unable to generate the URI and send it to the server. 
I have tried using this code

```
public MainPage()
    {
        /// Holds the push channel that is created or found.
        HttpNotificationChannel pushChannel;

        // The name of our push channel.
        string channelName = "RawSampleChannel";

        InitializeComponent();

        // Try to find the push channel.
        pushChannel = HttpNotificationChannel.Find(channelName);

        // If the channel was not found, then create a new connection to the push service.
        if (pushChannel == null)
        {
            pushChannel = new HttpNotificationChannel(channelName);

            // Register for all the events before attempting to open the channel.
            pushChannel.ChannelUriUpdated += new EventHandler<NotificationChannelUriEventArgs>(PushChannel_ChannelUriUpdated);
            pushChannel.ErrorOccurred += new EventHandler<NotificationChannelErrorEventArgs>(PushChannel_ErrorOccurred);
            pushChannel.HttpNotificationReceived += new EventHandler<HttpNotificationEventArgs>(PushChannel_HttpNotificationReceived);

            pushChannel.Open();

        }
        else
        {
            // The channel was already open, so just register for all the events.
            pushChannel.ChannelUriUpdated += new EventHandler<NotificationChannelUriEventArgs>(PushChannel_ChannelUriUpdated);
            pushChannel.ErrorOccurred += new EventHandler<NotificationChannelErrorEventArgs>(PushChannel_ErrorOccurred);
            pushChannel.HttpNotificationReceived += new EventHandler<HttpNotificationEventArgs>(PushChannel_HttpNotificationReceived);

            // Display the URI for testing purposes. Normally, the URI would be passed back to your web service at this point.
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(pushChannel.ChannelUri.ToString());
            MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Channel Uri is {0}",
                pushChannel.ChannelUri.ToString()));

        }
    }
```

But Visual Studio does not recognize `HttpNotificationChannel`. I have tried adding 'using Microsoft.Phone.Notification' but it doesn't find Phone within Microsoft package. I am assuming that it's deprecated for Windows 8.1? I am new to Windows, I could relate to GCM for Android and implemented the same for the Android app.

How can I get the URI for a Windows phone to send it to the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
var channel = await PushNotificationChannelManager.CreatePushNotificationChannelForApplicationAsync();
var uri = channel.Uri
```

There's a good sample [here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/push-and-periodic-de225603). Don't forget you have to associate your application with store which includes creating app and registering for WNS services to get client secret.

Comment: Thanks that worked after creating client secret . Can you help me on how to recieve a raw notification ? the code i have for it uses 'HttpNotificationChanel' which doesnt work.

Comment: Just use the sample I provided. There's a Scenario3_Listening.xaml.cs which contains listening part. It's a full client application which covers all aspects.